# Now whats the substitute for PageRank provided by google which recently got dead?

Tags: pagerank

PageRank provided by google is very helpful in many conditions where i need to know whether site is authenticate or not or to know the popularity of the site.

Mostly i used to with trusting site based on PageRank provided by Google and its always proved me helpful.

Now why google just stop such a good thing. Is their any other substitute of PageRank by which we can know how site is reliable.

Comment: Google don't do anything with out a reason. There must be some good idea which they will be working on. PageRank was good and I hope will come again. If you need specific information you can ask your queries on google help.

Answer (score 2):

Google is attempting to state that PageRank is no longer a significant part of their algorithm. The general feel is that this is false - but they've removed the ability to get the stat all the same.

There are products that offer page metrics to help you gauge their weight in different ways. The closest to page rank is probably Moz's Page Authority. There's also Ahrefs Url / Domain rank.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need handholding and reassurance by being given an arbitrary number that has little to do with current SERP technology, subscribe to:

1. Moz Page Authority
2. Majestic Marketing Search Engine
3. Ahrefs SEO tools

Otherwise, Google Pagerank is dead and done, isn't coming back and was updated so long ago when it was available that its relevance was highly suspect.